# Using gunfold to fill in positional arguments

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have the following Haskell program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data

data A = A Int Int
    deriving (Show, Typeable, Data)

main = print (f (toConstr (A undefined undefined)))

f :: Constr -> A
f c = _
```

I would like to implement `f` such that it has the type `Constr -> A`, and so that it is functionally equivalent to `A 1 2`. However, I do not want to use the actual constructor; I am only permitted to use the `Constr` for `A`, and `gunfold`. In effect, how can I use `gunfold` to apply a constructor, while providing different arguments for each constructor position? The more minimal/efficient, the better.

Here is some more context: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/24594 (specifically, see Michael Sloan's comment.) Essentially, we are generating code to call the constructors using Template Haskell; however, since we're basing this off of the `Data` instance, at the end of the day we have to go through `Data` to get the right behavior in the case that someone is using a virtual constructor.

Answer (score 4):

[`fromConstrM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Data.html#v:fromConstrM) is derived from `gunfold`. 
You can use it with `State` to trivially number the `Int` fields of a constructor.

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

numbered :: Data d => State Int d
numbered = fromMaybe (fail  "numbered - don't know which constructor to use next") $ gcast $ do
    i <- get
    put (i + 1)
    return i

f :: Constr -> A
f c = fst . runState (fromConstrM numbered c) $ 1
```

If you know what the arguments to the constructor would be you could keep a list of them in state and cast each one as it is used.

```
import Data.Dynamic

fillArgs :: Data d => State [Dynamic] d
fillArgs = do
    args <- get
    case args of 
        [] -> fail "fillArgs - not enough arguments provided"
        (x:xs) -> maybe
            (fail "fillArgs - type mismatch")
            (\x -> do
                put xs
                return x
            )
            (fromDynamic x)

applyConstr :: Data d => Constr -> [Dynamic] -> d
applyConstr c = fst . runState (fromConstrM fillArgs c)

f :: Constr -> A
f c = applyConstr c (map toDyn ([1..] :: [Int]))
```

Comment: Ugh, I guess I kind of suspected you could do that. How about with mixed type arguments like `A Int Bool Int Bool`? Do we need `HList`s now?

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang No, you don't need `HList`s if every type you are dealing with has a `Data` (or `Typeable`) instance. (Everything that has a `Data` instance also has a `Typeable` instance.) The type of every field exposed as part of a `Constr` for a `Data` instance should itself have a `Data` instance in order to be passed to the first argument of `gfoldl`. A `Dynamic` (also from the `Data/Typeable` world) is just a value along with its `Typeable` dictionary.

Comment: Oh I see, you've changed your example to use `Dynamic`. OK, I guess this works; although I'd still be interested in seeing a way to do this that the GHC optimizer could optimize away!